# How pass List and string as an Input Parameters to HttpDelete

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to remove many users from 1 group. I wrote the following method, but I dont know how to make a content string (concat or ...?) for httpdelete

```
    public async Task<bool> DeleteUsersFromGroup(List<string> usersId, string groupId)
        {
           var result = false
           var url = _url + "/api/DeleteUsersFromGroup?";
            
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var entity = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(usersId);
            var content = new StringContent(**entity**, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            
            try
            {
                var response = await _client.DeleteAsync(url);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responce = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(responce);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Is this even possible? i can deleted data by 1 id or make a post method

Comment: Please share what is your api like.What's the error message by using your code?

Comment: 500, because in this code not use uri